# performance monitoring rspec test: it "takes about 0 seconds to run an empty block" do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, block

I am not able to understand what I am being asked in this exercise(I have to get the following tests to pass):

```
require "performance_monitor"

require "time"  # loads up the Time.parse method -- do NOT create time.rb!

describe "Performance Monitor" do
  before do
    @eleven_am = Time.parse("2011-1-2 11:00:00")
  end

  it "takes about 0 seconds to run an empty block" do
    elapsed_time = measure do
    end
    elapsed_time.should be_within(0.1).of(0)
  end
```

I try creating a empty method but it won't pass.

```
def measure(number = 1)  
    number
end
```

or

```
def measure
end
```

I think I am not understanding what the test is asking me to build. What is it asking, and how can I interpret it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`measure` should accept a block, time its execution and return number of seconds that the block took to run. Here is the pseudocode (it translates pretty much directly to ruby code you need)

```
def measure(&block)
  time t1 = current time
  execute block
  return (current time - t1) # difference between current time *now* and
                             # time that was current before execution of the block
                             # which (the difference) means time the block took to run
end
```